# Python counting occurrence in a list: how to make it faster?

Tags: python, performance, list, counting

I have a list of strings which contains about 6 millions items, and I am trying to count the occurrence for each of the unique values.

Here is my code:

```
lines = [6 million strings]
unique_val = list(set(lines))    # contains around 500k items

mydict = {}
for val in unique_val:
    mydict[val] = lines.count(val)
```

I've found the above code works very slow given that the list I am counting is huge.

I'm wondering if there is a way to make it faster?

Many thanks

Comment: This may be large enough for `pyspark` and it would be well-suited for this type of problem.

Comment: Are you willing to use non-pure-python packages (like numpy or pyspark?).

Comment: Also, I edited your code so that it runs properly by using the right brace - I know editing code is usually frowned upon (it seemed like a very obvious typo), but if you meant the original for some reason rollback the edits

Comment: Do your data read from an external file? If so, I suggest to iterate over it line by line rather than load into the memory at one time.

Answer (score 3):

**Numpy Solution**

I think numpy will give you the fastest answer, using [unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
result = dict(zip(*np.unique(lines, return_counts=True)))
```

Numpy is pretty heavily optimized under the hood. Per the linked docs, the magic circles around the `return_counts` flag:

> `return_counts` : bool, optional
>
> If True, also return the number of times each unique value comes up in ar.

---

**Timing**

I timed your original approach, the counter approach

```
result = Counter(lines)
```

and the numpy approach on a set generated by

```
N = 1000000
lines = [chr(i%100) for i in range(N) ]
```

Obviously, that test isn't great coverage, but it's a start.

You're approach operated in 0.584s; DeepSpace's Counter in 0.162 (**3.5x speedup**), and numpy in 0.0861 (**7x speedup**). Again, this may depend on a lot of factor's including the type of data you have: the conclusion may be that either numpy or a Counter will provide a speedup, with a counter not requiring an external library

Answer (score 2):

Calling `list.count` is very expensive. Dictionary access (O(1) amortized time) and the `in` operator however are relatively cheap. The following snippet shows much better time complexity.

```
def stats(lines):
    histogram = {}
    for s in lines:
        if s in histogram:
            histogram[s] += 1
        else:
            histogram[s] = 1
    return histogram
```

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to use the `collections` module.

```
counts = dict()
for line in lines:
    counts[line] = counts.get(line,0) + 1
```

Or if you just don't want to use `Counter`

```
from collection import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
for line in lines:
    counts[line] += 1
```

Comment: Hi michael, how does that first one work? It looks like counts is not initialized to anything, so I don't see how it gets updated? (When I run it, it doesn't seem to work either...). The "get" function looks for a key and returns 0 if that key isn't there, but since we never add any keys, won't it always be 0?

Comment: @en_Knight, :) It obviously doesn't work. I missed the `+1` at the end. I have edited it now

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
from collections import defaultdict
import collections

lines = [600 million strings]

d = defaultdict(int)
for line in lines:
    for word, count in collections.Counter(line).items():
        d[word] += count
```

Comment: Why would you do this over DeepSpace's, when that his seems much more concise for the same result? (Granted, I don't think he should have the call to set in his)

Comment: @en_Knight, thx for pointing out this. I just edited my answer.

Comment: Hmm I still don't understand how this is better than  `d = Counter(lines)`. Why are we looping, calling Counter multiple times, and dictionary copies? Is there a memory optimization you're doing maybe?

Comment: @en_Knight, If OP store the data in an external file, it would be very helpful to iterate read it line by line rather than load into the memory at one time.